# What's the difference between Spring Boot's @Configuration and @AutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

And most important, what's the reason behind the "Auto" prefix? Classes annotated with `@Configuration` rather than `@AutoConfiguration` are less automatic or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Configuration` is a spring framework annotation and not strictly bound to `spring-boot`. It was introduced when spring started to allow programmatic creation of `spring-beans` as to move forward from `xml` definitions of beans.

`@AutoConfiguration` is a `spring-boot` specific annotation not commonly available in spring framework. The reason it exists, is for external providers that cooperate with `spring-boot` to be able to mark some classes in some libraries they provide with this annotation as to inform `spring-boot` that those classes could be parsed and make some initializations during start up of spring application **automatically**.

So if some regular programmer that develops some application happens to have `kafka` in dependencies then some beans will automatically be created and added in application context and will be ready for the programmer to use, although he has not defined any configuration for them. `Spring-boot` already knows this as the `kafka` provider has already informed by marking some class in the jar they provide with the annotation `@AutoConfiguration`.

For this reason `@AutoConfiguration` has some more powerful configurations available as `before`, `after`, `beforeName`, `afterName` as to allow the provider to specify when the configuration is applied during application startup if some order is necessary.

So this annotation is not to be used from some regular programmer that develops an application using `spring-boot`. It is for someone that develops a library that other users might use with `spring-boot`. One such example is `kafka` library.

For this to work in a `spring-boot` project `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is needed as well, to enable auto configuration.

From spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html)

> Spring Boot auto-configuration attempts to automatically configure
> your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have
> added. For example, if HSQLDB is on your classpath, and you have not
> manually configured any database connection beans, then Spring Boot
> auto-configures an in-memory database.

`@Configuration` instead is to be used from some regular programmer that develops an application using `spring-boot` or `spring-framework` as to inform the framework for which beans should be created and how.

Answer (score 4):

`@AutoConfiguration` was introduced in 2.7 with the idea to mark all auto-configurations with its dedicated annotation and move away from `spring.factories` for auto-configuration imports in 3.0 as described in [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29698).

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfiguration.html):

> [`@AutoConfiguration`] indicates that a class provides configuration that can be
> automatically applied by Spring Boot. Auto-configuration classes are
> regular `@Configuration` with the exception that
> `Configuration#proxyBeanMethods()` is always false.

Usually, `@AutoConfiguration` classes automatically configure an application based on the dependencies that are present on the classpath. Those classes are generally marked as `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations that detect the presence or absence of specific classes.

Additionally, if a configuration needs to be applied in a specific order, you can use the `before`, `beforeName`, `after`, and `afterName` attributes on the `@AutoConfiguration`, unlike `@Configuration` which doesn't provide those attributes.

Comment: Since proxyBeanMethods being always false is the difference between the two annotations, I can assume that the comment you added is valid for both annotations? If yes, it doesn't really answers the meaning behind the "auto" prefix.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro check my answer below. The biggest difference is that `@Configuration` is a spring annotation while `@AutoConfiguration` is a `spring-boot` only annotation. Starting from this if you read my answer you could understand how the `auto` prefix came into play

Comment: @birca123 Yes, it is more clear now. Thank you. However, I wish you had been more incisive on the difference between the two annotations, rather than focusing on the definition of AutoConfiguration. From Panagiotis, I got that Configuration is for bean initialization and AutoConfiguration is for automatically booting dependencies, which can also be used for configuring beans, but provides specific options for helping set up booting steps (I think).

Comment: So can i say that after using @AutoConfiguration, we no longer need to manually update spring.factories, and will no longer see such file anymore in any of the modern future starter implementation

Comment: Since Spring Boot 2.7, loading auto-configurations from `spring.factories` is deprecated (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-M2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-27)), but it is still used to register listeners for example.